# How to customize system menu when click menu button?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I'm on **Android** App and i click on **menu** button at mobile device, **settings** menu appear. How i can add new item **Facebook** like at this setting menu ?

Comment: What is "mobile device system menu"? Feel free to upload a screenshot.

Comment: @CommonsWare i think he created a project with Eclipse and didn't modify the default menu: maybe "mobile device system menu" is "settings".

Comment: @JaAd y are right "mobile device system menu" is "settings"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:title="@string/menu_facebook_like"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_like"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Then on your code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle menu item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.like:
    // Do what you want when "like" is pressed
    return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Of course you have to find a "like" icon (ask to Google) and resize it for the ActionBar/Menu.

Comment: I didnot need to add new menu i need to add new item "facebook" to settings menu